# Given the following code, what will be the value stored in variable result? python

Tags: python

I was going through exam practice

```
someNumbers = [10, 5, 7, 3, 2] 
result = sum(someNumbers[1:4])
```

How come the answer is `15`?

Shouldnt sum means adding `5+7+3+2`

how exactly do they work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, `sum` does mean sum of the specified elements. However, `[1:4]` means elements at indices 1 to 3 (inclusive). The element at the index of 4 is *not* included.

Therefore, `someNumbers[1:4]` is actually just `[5, 7, 3]` which does sum to 15.

To get the last four elements in the list above, you would do either `someNumbers[1:]` or `someNumbers[1:5]`

Comment: so if its 0:4 then it wil start from 10, 5 ,7

Comment: @user3543831, 10, 5, 7, 3 (since the indices are 0, 1, 2, 3)

Comment: @user3543831, The second value in [a:b] doesn't specify length. It specifies the ending index

Comment: @user3543831, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thanks